# Display html element in a table

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to display elements in a table but I don't understand how can I display it like this:

| Store_id1 | Store_id2 | Store_id3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Budget1 | Budget2 | Budget3 |

my table is:

| Store_id1 |
| --- |
| Budget1 |
| Store_id2 |
| Budget2 |
| Store_id3 |
| Budget3 |

My code is :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<table class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <div *ngFor="let store of stores">
    <ng-container matColumnDef={{store.store_id}}>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">{{store.store_id}}</th>
        <td scope="row">{{store.budget}}</td>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</table>
```

EDIT.

So the problem is that I would to show my data as:

> Store1       Store2        Store3
>
> Budget1      Budget2       Budget3

But in my way the data are show like:

**Store1**
Budget1
**Store2**
Budget2
**Store3**
Budget3

Comment: Are you asking how to make columns in HTML tables? See [MDN docs: HTML tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table) which has examples for you.

Comment: Aside: I think you have a typo in the first `th` tag: `scrope` rather than `scope`. Additionally you can't nest a `div` directly in a `table`; it must be in a `th` or a `td`.

Comment: Thank you @PeterKrebs for answer, my problem is that my data are showed in different way ( I edit my question)

Comment: @mykaf yes scrope is only a error during copying here code :)

Comment: @mykaf Ok i solved the problem, you are right about the nested div. I have change the for in a td and now the data are show correctly

Comment: You must change your loop so that you render the `th` in a separate `tr` from the `td`. I would recommend you create the HTML table you want and then decide how to create the loops to make that HTML happen.

Comment: @PeterKrebs, why must the `th` and `td` be in separate `tr`s? Is that an angular thing? I put them in the same row all the time, and I've never seen any documentation that prohibits it.

Comment: This is pure HTML and has nothing to do with JavaScript or angular. tr means "table row" so naturally if you want things to be in a different row, have a tr.

Comment: *facepalming self* I see it now. Was not looking closely at the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that, angular material table, has template part, where you shape your table. These are `matColumnDef`/`matHeaderCellDef`/`matCellDef`. With your loop, you attempt to setup table with dynamic columns, yet empty.

Then `displayedColumns` also has to be dynamic as well, because it controls, which columns to show or not.

Data is actually filled, when after template is prepared and `dataSource` receives data.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<!-- somewhere you get value of store in scope -->
<!-- there you have to add displayedColumns = store.map(s => s.store_id) -->

<table mat-table class="mat-elevation-z8" [dataSource]="store">
  <!-- this loop defines table template, i.e. columns -->
  <div *ngFor="let store of stores">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{store.store_id}}">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{store.store_id}}</th>

      <!-- actual data is coming from dataSource, this is implicit loop from your perspective -->
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let s">{{s.weight}}</td>
    </ng-container>
  </div>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let s; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Example above is rough monkey typing, does not pretend to be valid code, only for illustration purposes. Valid code will have TypeScript parts as well, where `store` is retrieved and `displayedColumns` calculated.